# About apk installation

Tags: applications, apk

I have doubt on installation of apk file. Where does the apk file store RAM or ROM ?

As we know that RAM is  volatile memory and ROM is secondary storage and also  when is system shutdown, is the data  erased from RAM?

Comment: apk files you install are usually stored in /data/app which is typically part of the /data partition on your internal storage. What is the problem you are having, are all settings/applications/data erased when you reboot? Sounds like a hardware or ROM problem. Please update your question with your specific device, Android version, and clarify the issue. Thanks.

Comment: There is no accessible ROM in Smartphones, only FLASH. Apps are installed to FLASH memory and loaded from there to RAM.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! I have modified the content of your question, if wish it to edit it further please do, but make sure the question is clear enough to attract a good answer.

Comment: Just to be clear, where I used the term "ROM" in my previous comment I was referring to the operating system and it possibly being corrupt, not "Read Only Memory".